# How to get all listbox items names using access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've a list box in access trying to get listbox items in a variable and comapre those items with table column names i.e check all list box items with table columns if any of those are missing. How do i get listbox names.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. You can easily find all controls that are of type 'listbox' on a form. You can easily get all items in the listbox (or only selected items) and you can easily get all field names for a table or recordset. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The `Controls.Item(index).ControlType` property will return what type of control is on your form. You can loop through the `Form.Controls` collection looking for `acListBox`. `Control.Name` will return the control name. For example:

```
'placed this code into a form's module
dim i as long
dim c as control

For i = 0 to Me.Controls.count - 1
    set c = Me.Controls.Item(i)
    If c.ControlType = acListBox Then
        debug.print c.Name
    End if        
Next i
```